# Designing latex template for song

Tags: templates

[image: Designing LaTeX template]
Please someone help me in LaTeX to create layout as shown in the figure.

Comment: Hi Biki Teron and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/topic/music

Comment: Fom songs package, I was not able to print Doh is G and curly bracket as shown in the figure. Please help me to find the correct template.

Comment: This very much looks like it's done with the `songs` package. If you provide a MWE I'm sure people will be able to fill in the blanks